# Can I use a DataTable for a AutoCompleteExtender from AjaxToolKit

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, autocompleteextender

I built a ASP.NET Webapplication and I have a TextBox where a User can find a other User. For this I want use the AutoCompleteExtender from AjaxToolKit. The Data I get from the Active Directory. If I start my Page the Application create a DataTable with all UserDate from ActiveDirectory and my Question is.

Can I use a DataTabe for the Informations in a AutoCompleteExtender? If I can use this how I can use this ?

Comment: Instead of using **Ajax AutoCompleteExtender** why don't you use **webservice** and **J-query** to auto complete text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) you can't. Not only you can't use a DataTable but you must implement a web service and within it, a webmethod with a very specific signature.

If you don't mind using jQuery, I can show you an example using jQuery.

**Update:**

Using jQuery all you need to do is include the following libraries in your markup:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On your markup, you can add an `asp:hiddenElement` and the text element that will be used for autocompletion as so:

```
<asp:HiddenElement id="hdnAutoComplete" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="txtAutoComplete" runat="server" />
```

Now, you just add the following Javascript function:

```
$(function(){
var items = eval($('#<%=hdnAutoComplete.ClientID%>').val());

  $( "#<%=txtAutoComplete.ClientID%>" ).autocomplete({
     source: items
   });

});
```

Finally, you need to set the elements that you are going to use for autocompletion from codebhind. Since you want to use a DataTable, I'll show you an easy way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataTable t = ...//your datatable is this

     var query = (from c in t.AsEnumerable()
                 select c.Field<string>("NameOfTheColumnYouWant")).ToArray();

     //this will create a javascript array on the client-side when it's eval'd 
     hdnAutoComplete.Value = "["+string.Join(",",query)+"]";

}
```

Read more examples from jQuery UI's official documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).